# Removing object on a tableView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITableView` and when the user swipes on one of the cells he can delete the cell (delete the object from the array).

But for example, when the user swipes on a cell in the middle of the table the animation is made on the last cell (the one on the bottom) like in this video:

https://vid.me/D0pi

Here is the code for this deletion:

```
//Removing cell from "AroundersTableView"(UITableView) with UITableViewRowAnimationLeft
[self.AroundersTableView beginUpdates];
[self.Arounders removeObjectAtIndex:cellRowToDelete];
[self.AroundersTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellRowToDelete inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[self.AroundersTableView endUpdates];

//Saving Arounders
[self saveArounders];

//Creating "newTableFrame"(CGRect) and setting it to current "AroundersTableView"'s frame will one less cell
CGRect newTableFrame=self.AroundersTableView.frame;
newTableFrame.origin.y+=44;

//Animating "AroundersTableView" to the new frame
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.AroundersTableView.frame=newTableFrame;
}];

//ReConfiguring "AroundersTableView"(UITableView) height
[self performSelector:@selector(configureTableViewsHeight) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

//Reloading "AroundersTableView"(UITableView) data
[self.AroundersTableView reloadData];
```

Note: `configureTableViewsHeight` is just a method the makes the tableView height to be the `cell.height*Arounders.count` (cells height * number of cells).

I have no idea why it's happening.

Why is it? How can I make the animation on the correct cell (the all the cells above it are going down and hiding the red part)?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you configuring cellRowToDelete?  It looks like your index is getting messed up.  Have you set a breakpoint and looked into cellRowToDelete to ensure it contains the correct row?

Comment: Calling `reloadData` on the table will negate the animation of `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. Try it without the reload.

Comment: @Paulw11 Same problem

Comment: @fbara The correct cell is being deleted, the animation is just on the wrong one, so `cellRowToDelete` is correct

Comment: Your animation block should be between begin and endupdates because that is the place where row is getting delete from the tableview after that next row wil takes its place.

Comment: @ArunGupta It's working but I know found what the problem is, `UITableViewRowAnimationLeft` animation is taking all the cells below the deleted cell and moving them up, I need the opposite, I want the animation to take all the cells *above** the deleted cell and moving them down, do you know how can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: I think I need to open a different question for this, but thank you!